# ReplayKit doesn't work in iOS sample SpriteKit project code

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3, replaykit

I am using the sample SpriteKit project in Xcode to test ReplayKit but it just displays the normal app without the without the `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` appearing. Just the black screen with the `Hello, World!` label. I'm not sure what I am missing. Below is the `GameViewController` class details.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import ReplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController, RPPreviewViewControllerDelegate {

 //weak var previewControllerDelegate: RPPreviewViewControllerDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Start", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(startRecording))


    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true

    }



}


func startRecording() {
    let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()

    recorder.startRecording{ [unowned self] (error) in
        if let unwrappedError = error {
            print(unwrappedError.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Stop", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.stopRecording))
        }
    }
}

func stopRecording() {
    let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()

    recorder.stopRecording { [unowned self] (preview, error) in
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Start", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.startRecording))

        if let unwrappedPreview = preview {
            unwrappedPreview.previewControllerDelegate = self
            self.present(unwrappedPreview, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

func previewControllerDidFinish(_ previewController: RPPreviewViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        return .allButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .all
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

Comment: Can someone please help me

Comment: The `rightBarButtonItem` button doesn't appear because the sample SpriteKit project code doesn't have a navigation bar. Perhaps you should add a `UIButton` or a `SKSpriteNode` button.